# Can you Queue Threads or Processes in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, ffmpeg

I have a function that saves files after modifying them (video files being modified by ffmpeg). The function utilizes a binary, calling a sub process on it. The problem I am having is if I call this function two soon after the first run (ie, the first process is still running) the second one will not execute, or it will overwrite the first one.

I am still new to processes and threads, and I don't want to just have the function create a bunch of threads, as I am afraid this could just get out of hand (unfounded fear?). **How do I get the function to queue up another job and execute it when the binary is free?**

Code:

```
pipe = sp.Popen([ffmpeg_binary,"-i", sample_vid, "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
                 "-ss", start_time, "-t", end_time, "-sn", output_file_name ])
```

The output_file_name variable checks if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will set the variable equal to the input file name + index +.extension.

Comment: do you have threads already?  what do you do after the process finishes?  can you just use different output filenames?

Comment: Don't have threads already for this. Just something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just call `subprocess.wait()` on each process before proceeding to the next. This blocks until the process is finished, ensuring that all subprocesses run sequentially. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

Comment: Oh thanks for the link! So in a loop, just for sub_process in sp_list:  sub_process.whatever() sub_process.wait()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only call external command and not play with all processes/threads low-level api, use library [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh/).

Then you can just do like that:

```
from sh import ffmpeg

ffmpeg(arg1, arg2)  # call 1
ffmpeg(arg2, arg3)  # call 2

# if you want custom binary

from sh import Command
ffmpeg = Command('/path/to/ffmpeg')
```

Comment: Is this cross-platform or just linux?

Comment: I am not sure, I never used it on windows. In docs I did not find any note about it. So, just try.